# How does BUNDLE help to improve webRTC connection/performance? By how much roughly?

Tags: performance, webrtc, bundle

According to the doc here:

> One obvious benefit of doing this is reducing the ICE negotiation time as the number of ICE candidates is reduced.

https://webrtcstandards.info/sdp-bundle/

BUNDLE is able to improve the performance. However, I fail to see how it can do so. Let's assume that this is the scenario I am in:

1. Forced TURN x 2 on some URL's `80` and `443` port
2. 1 to 1 connection. Let's not talk about conferencing situations.
3. Starting from scratch: ICE tricking, sdp offer... all the way to media stream in.
4. Audio and video goes 2 way.

I understand that bundle will mux audio and video into a single stream and send it over, so it can probably reduce the trickling time, at least by 1/2.

How about the part after sdp received by both parties and starts to send streams? Does it improve the connection time there too, compare to `balance` mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, ICE paces the stun requests used for connectivity checks (hidden somewhere in RFC 5245). I strongly doubt this has an actual effect though.

The main argument for using bundle is that you only need to punch a single hole in the NAT and can not run into weird situations where the hole for audio is punched but the hole for video is not.

Comment: so in balance mode, we see audio and video come in different times. Is this related to hole punching too? Thank you for the answer.

Comment: this should not be noticeable. Also synchronization should still be handled regardless of bundle.

Comment: thanks you for the comment again. I didn't make myself clear. The video and audio are in sync when they are both appearing. There is no sync issue when they are both there.

However, sometimes video stream shows up first and sometimes audio. That will surely not happen in bundle, right?

Also, could you please recommend some readings of webRTC internals after the sdp exchanges. I found a lot of literature online before sdp exchange, but not much after it. Thanks again.